# Table and view index comparison and CTE iteration

Tags: sql, sql-server, foreach, iteration, common-table-expression

As an exercise, I wrote a small script that

1. Finds the indexes and columns on a given table
2. Finds indexed views (and their columns) with dependencies to that table
3. Compares the indexes on the views are to those on the table, to see if any of the indexed views are identical.

This third step is giving me problem. I can't seem to get my head around doing the iteration and comparison. Was looking at using a CTE to compare each index column, but it is not turning out correctly. Any help would be most helpful.

```
DECLARE @table_name VARCHAR(1000)
SET @table_name = 'dbo.tableName'

DROP TABLE IF EXISTS tempdb.dbo.#tmp_TableIndexesAndColumns; --
DROP TABLE IF EXISTS tempdb.dbo.#tmp_ViewsIndexesAndColumns;
--------------------------------------------------------
-- qTable - Get Table Indexes and their Columns
--------------------------------------------------------
CREATE TABLE #tmp_TableIndexesAndColumns
(
    tmpID INT IDENTITY(1, 1) NOT NULL PRIMARY KEY,
    table_schema_id INT NOT NULL,
    table_schema VARCHAR (5) NOT NULL,
    table_id INT NOT NULL,
    table_name VARCHAR(1000) NOT NULL,
    table_index_id INT NOT NULL,
    table_index_name VARCHAR(1000) NOT NULL,
    table_index_type_id INT NOT NULL,
    table_index_type VARCHAR(50) NOT NULL,
    table_is_unique BIT NOT NULL,
    table_column_id INT NOT NULL,
    table_column_name VARCHAR(1000) NOT NULL,
    table_is_included BIT NOT NULL
);

INSERT INTO #tmp_TableIndexesAndColumns
SELECT 
    obj_table.schema_id
    ,SCHEMA_NAME(obj_table.schema_id)
    ,obj_table.object_id
    ,obj_table.[name] AS table_name
    ,i.index_id index_id
    ,i.[name] AS index_name
    ,i.[type] AS index_type_id
       ,CASE
           WHEN i.[type] = 1 THEN
               'Clustered index'
           WHEN i.[type] = 2 THEN
               'Nonclustered unique index'
           WHEN i.[type] = 3 THEN
               'XML index'
           WHEN i.[type] = 4 THEN
               'Spatial index'
           WHEN i.[type] = 5 THEN
               'Clustered columnstore index'
           WHEN i.[type] = 6 THEN
               'Nonclustered columnstore index'
           WHEN i.[type] = 7 THEN
               'Nonclustered hash index'
           ELSE
               ''
       END AS index_type
       ,i.is_unique
       ,col_idx.column_id
       ,col_idx.[name] AS [column_name]
       ,col_idx.is_included_column
FROM sys.objects obj_table
    INNER JOIN sys.indexes i
        ON obj_table.object_id = i.object_id
    CROSS APPLY
(
    SELECT col.column_id
            ,col.[name]
           ,ic.is_included_column
    FROM sys.index_columns ic
        INNER JOIN sys.columns col
            ON ic.object_id = col.object_id
               AND ic.column_id = col.column_id
    WHERE ic.object_id = obj_table.object_id
          AND ic.index_id = i.index_id
) col_idx
WHERE obj_table.object_id = OBJECT_ID(@table_name)
      AND obj_table.is_ms_shipped <> 1
      AND i.index_id > 0
ORDER BY i.index_id, col_idx.column_id ;

--------------------------------------------------------
--  qTable - Get View Indexes and their Columns
--  (Views that Referencing Our Table)
--------------------------------------------------------
CREATE TABLE #tmp_ViewsIndexesAndColumns
(
    tmpID INT IDENTITY(1, 1) NOT NULL PRIMARY KEY,
    view_schema_id INT NOT NULL,
    view_schema VARCHAR (5) NOT NULL,
    view_id INT NOT NULL,
    view_name VARCHAR(1000) NOT NULL,
    view_index_id INT NOT NULL,
    view_index_name VARCHAR(1000) NOT NULL,
    view_index_type_id INT NOT NULL,
    view_index_type VARCHAR(50) NOT NULL,
    view_is_unique BIT NOT NULL,
    referenced_column_id INT NOT NULL,
    referenced_column_name VARCHAR(1000) NOT NULL,
    referenced_is_included BIT NOT NULL
);

INSERT INTO #tmp_ViewsIndexesAndColumns
SELECT DISTINCT 
    obj_view.schema_id
    ,SCHEMA_NAME(obj_view.schema_id) AS view_schema
    ,obj_view.object_id
    ,obj_view.[name] AS view_name
    ,i.index_id
    ,i.[name] AS index_name
    ,i.[type] AS index_type_id
       ,CASE
           WHEN i.[type] = 1 THEN
               'Clustered index'
           WHEN i.[type] = 2 THEN
               'Nonclustered unique index'
           WHEN i.[type] = 3 THEN
               'XML index'
           WHEN i.[type] = 4 THEN
               'Spatial index'
           WHEN i.[type] = 5 THEN
               'Clustered columnstore index'
           WHEN i.[type] = 6 THEN
               'Nonclustered columnstore index'
           WHEN i.[type] = 7 THEN
               'Nonclustered hash index'
           ELSE
               ''
       END AS index_type
       ,i.is_unique
       ,col_idx.column_id
       ,col_idx.[name] AS [column_name]
       ,col_idx.is_included_column
FROM sys.objects obj_table
JOIN sys.sql_expression_dependencies sed
     on sed.referenced_id = obj_table.object_id
join sys.objects obj_view
     on sed.referencing_id = obj_view.object_id
    JOIN sys.indexes i
        ON obj_view.object_id = i.object_id
    CROSS APPLY
(
    SELECT col.column_id
            ,col.[name]
           ,ic.is_included_column
    FROM sys.index_columns ic
        INNER JOIN sys.columns col
            ON ic.object_id = col.object_id
               AND ic.column_id = col.column_id
    WHERE ic.object_id = obj_view.object_id
          AND ic.index_id = i.index_id
) col_idx
WHERE obj_table.object_id = OBJECT_ID(@table_name)
      AND obj_view.is_ms_shipped <> 1
      AND i.index_id > 0
 ORDER BY obj_view.object_id, i.index_id, i.[name];

--------------------------------------------------------
--  qCompare - Find Identical View and Table Indexes
--------------------------------------------------------
WITH cte_table_index AS
(SELECT 
     ROW_NUMBER()  OVER (PARTITION BY tbl.table_index_id ORDER BY tbl.table_column_id) group_id
    ,tbl.table_index_id
    ,tbl.table_column_id
      FROM #tmp_TableIndexesAndColumns tbl
      UNION ALL       
      SELECT
     ROW_NUMBER()  OVER (PARTITION BY tbl.table_index_id ORDER BY tbl.table_column_id) group_id
      ,vw.view_index_id
      ,vw.referenced_column_id
FROM #tmp_TableIndexesAndColumns tbl
INNER JOIN #tmp_ViewsIndexesAndColumns vw
ON tbl.table_column_id = vw.referenced_column_id)
SELECT * FROM cte_table_index


DROP TABLE IF EXISTS tempdb.dbo.#tmp_TableIndexesAndColumns; 
DROP TABLE IF EXISTS tempdb.dbo.#tmp_ViewsIndexesAndColumns;
```

Thank you in advance!

Comment: I think this is relational division. You want all views and tables which have exactly matching columns and indexes correct?. Any reason you are using temp tables for this, I think it can be done in one query

Comment: Thanks for replying Charlieface: I am looking for full and partial index matches. For example: Table A has index B. Index B uses columns, 1,4,7. Dependent View A has index C. Index C uses 1,4,7,9. The first three columns of Index B and Index C match. The query should tell me there is a match for the first 3 columns, but not the fourth (column 9). 

The temps were a staging step. Was figuring out what I needed. Intent was to do the compare then put into one query if possible, but I am stuck on the comparison.

Comment: What about column ordering? what actual result do you want: just the table name and view name, or also which index matches, or also the index definition? Each of those is harder than the previous.

Comment: Which indexes match, exactly. To modify the previous example: Say Table A, index B now uses 1,4,7 and INCLUDES 9. View A, Index C (which uses 1,4,7,9) would NOT be the same because column 9 is not an included column.  In addition, the script would compare the column order (index_column_id). Again, example: Table A, Index B using 1,4,7 would be different than View A, Index C if C columns were arranged as 4,1,7. 

Again, thanks for looking at the problem.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here is my attempt.

We take all indexes for a table, match references in views, join indexes of table and view.

We then filter as follows:

There must not exist anything in the full join of the two sets of index columns. This full join is filtered to only include non-matching index columns (the inner `NOT EXISTS` is just short-hand for doing a nullable comparison on all those different things to compare, there is no `FROM` here):

```sql
SELECT 
    obj_table.schema_id
    ,SCHEMA_NAME(obj_table.schema_id)
    ,obj_table.object_id
    ,obj_table.[name] AS table_name
    ,iT.index_id index_id
    ,iT.[name] AS index_name
    ,iT.[type] AS index_type_id
    ,iT.type_desc AS index_type
    ,iT.is_unique

    ,obj_view.schema_id
    ,SCHEMA_NAME(obj_view.schema_id) AS view_schema
    ,obj_view.object_id
    ,obj_view.[name] AS view_name
    ,iV.index_id index_id
    ,iV.[name] AS index_name
    ,iV.[type] AS index_type_id
    ,iV.type_desc AS index_type
    ,iV.is_unique
FROM sys.objects obj_table
JOIN sys.indexes iT
    ON obj_table.object_id = iT.object_id
JOIN sys.sql_expression_dependencies sed
    on sed.referenced_id = obj_table.object_id
JOIN sys.objects obj_view
    on sed.referencing_id = obj_view.object_id
JOIN sys.indexes iV
    ON obj_view.object_id = iV.object_id

WHERE NOT EXISTS (SELECT 1
    FROM sys.index_columns icT
    INNER JOIN sys.columns colT
        ON icT.object_id = colT.object_id AND icT.column_id = colT.column_id
    -- outer ref
        AND icT.object_id = obj_table.object_id
        AND icT.index_id = iT.index_id

    FULL JOIN (sys.index_columns icV
        INNER JOIN sys.columns colV
            ON icV.object_id = colV.object_id AND icV.column_id = colV.column_id
        -- outer ref
        AND icV.object_id = obj_view.object_id
        AND icV.index_id = iV.index_id
    
    ) ON icV.index_column_id = icT.index_column_id

    WHERE NOT EXISTS (
      SELECT
        icT.index_column_id,
        icT.is_descending_key,
        icT.key_ordinal,
        colT.user_type_id,
        colT.max_length,
        colT.precision,
        colT.scale,
        colT.collation_name,
        colT.is_nullable
      INTERSECT
      SELECT
        icV.index_column_id,
        icV.is_descending_key,
        icV.key_ordinal,
        colV.user_type_id,
        colV.max_length,
        colV.precision,
        colV.scale,
        colV.collation_name,
        colV.is_nullable
    )
)

WHERE obj_table.object_id = OBJECT_ID(@table_name)
      AND obj_table.is_ms_shipped <> 1
      AND i.index_id > 0;
```

Comment: Hey Thanks - Cf - Let me give a go! needed a few tweeks but I like the data coming back. May take a day or so (RL project issues) to review and give you an update!

Comment: CharlieFace. Sorry for the delay in getting back to you. I like your solution so far. I think I'm almost there. The last piece is getting the column names that are redundant, but I having issues. If you have any suggestions, that also would be most helpful!

Comment: Not clear. What do you mean "redundant"? Surely they are just the same columns again, as we are going for an exact match

Comment: Hey Charlie, kinda had my head in my pants with that last comment. I wanted the actual table column names the view was referencing in sql_expression_dependencies. I got it using COL_NAME(referenced_id,referenced_minor_id). There are more changes I need to make, but that is enough for now. You got me by the hard part. Thanks!